# How to connect to Postgres on localhost with URL: "jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/db123"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, jdbc

I am able to connect to a postgres 10 instance on my local Win10 machine with pgAdmin 4 and "**localhost**" as a hostname, but when I change the hostname to "**database**" I cannot connect. How to fix it?

I've added to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 database
```

It didn't help so I've also edited `%HOME%\PostgreSQL10\data\pg_hba.conf` adding this line

```
host    all             all             database                md5
```

No success.

What can I try next?

UPD: there is nothing useful in server logs `%HOME%\PostgreSQL10\data\log\postgresql-2018-09-05_181552.log` (should/can I enable some restrictive logging level?)

```
2018-09-05 18:15:52.677 EEST [5820] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-09-05 18:15:42 EEST
2018-09-05 18:15:52.702 EEST [20656] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

and after I stoped the postgres service:

```
2018-09-05 18:15:52.677 EEST [5820] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-09-05 18:15:42 EEST
2018-09-05 18:15:52.702 EEST [20656] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2018-09-05 18:16:45.230 EEST [20656] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2018-09-05 18:16:45.236 EEST [20656] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2018-09-05 18:16:45.242 EEST [20656] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 20400) exited with exit code 1
2018-09-05 18:16:45.244 EEST [15252] LOG:  shutting down
2018-09-05 18:16:45.322 EEST [20656] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

[image: pgAdmin 4]

Comment: What error do you get?  Both on the client, and in the server log.

Comment: @jjanes I posted the logs of the server, but they don't contain any error, maybe I should enable some confg switch..

Comment: If the sequence of events is as shown in your update, you tried to connect to the database with pgAdmin after you had shut it down.  If that is the true sequence, it would explain why you couldn't connect--the database is no longer running.